# Why entity cannot have uniqueness constraints with to-one mandatory inverse relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data

Why entity cannot have uniqueness constraints with to-one mandatory inverse relationship?
Having two entities:

- Person

property: name

relationship: department (to-one, non-optional)

- Department

property: title (unique constraint)

relationship: person (to-many, optional)

Model won't compile in iOS 9, XCode 7.0.1 with misconfigured entity error:

> Misconfigured Entity: Entity Department cannot have uniqueness
>   constraints and to-one mandatory inverse relationship
>   Person.department

**Update:**
Question is still relevant in XCode 8.3.1.

Comment: Seems like a bug in XCode 7.0.1 – 8.3.1. Will file a radar later.

Comment: Also an issue with XCode 13.2.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The underlying problem is most likely caused by the sqlite standard. I'm not sure about that. How ever, it's very likely that it is because of the limitations of sqlite. I found some posts on the internet, where people had issues with multiple constraints on one table and thats most likely the reason why the two-table workaround works.

**Long answer:**

It's pretty late, but I hope it helps anyway.

This occurs when your Entity has an unique constraint and a mandatory relation. I guess it's because of the added unique constraint behaviors in iOS 9.0. However you can solve this in two ways:

You remove the unique constraint or make the relation optional. You could handle an optional relation in code. But it won't be a nice solution.

OR

You can use a workaround. **You can have both.** You can create a super class having a unique constraint. However this won't work without problems, too.

Let's you have three entities. A, B and C.

A is your super class and B is a sub class of A and C is a sub class of A, too. A has an unique constraint on it's property primaryKey. When saving instances of B and C, you can not have a B and C with the same primaryKey. Because CoreData will manage both as A.

You could change A to have two Properties:

- int: originalPrimaryKey (NO unique constraint)
- string: primaryKey (unique constraint)

You can now map your primaryKeys to originalPrimaryKey and when setting the originalPrimaryKey you could set the string primaryKey property to CLASS_NAME.{originalPrimaryKey}. This would allow you to have the behavior, you would expect. But you have to add a workaround for primaryKeys.

Comment: Handling optional relation is much less effort than unwanted subclassing. Thank you for the workarounds, but the reason why is undisclosed - you just paraphrased my input, so I cannot accept this as an answer.

Comment: The underlying problem is most likely caused by the sqlite standard. I'm not sure about that, so I did not mention it. How ever, it's very likely that it is because of the limitations of sqlite. I found some posts on the internet, where people had issues with multiple constraints on one table and thats most likely the reason why the two-table workaround works.

Comment: Thanks. I've added your comment in answer for others to find it easy.

Comment: It is shocking just how bad CoreData can be, I shouldn’t have to choose between uniqueness and enforced relationships, it’s pretty basic database stuff, even MySQL can handle that.  Why am I continuing to use this when alternatives exist!

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to add constraints with existing entity with records , 
The solution is 
1. delete all records from existing entity
2. delete existing relationships with the entity .
3. Regenerate the +CoreDataClass and +CoreDataProperties agin.

Comment: This is, for me at least, a compile time error, so doubt there be data is the issue.  In fact deleting the app so there is no data still produces the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Make your relationship properties "optional". That fixed this problem in my case.

Comment: The question is explicitly about **mandatory** relationship. I know it works with optional, but lacks validation then.